# How does the Contours→{{f_1, g1}, {f_2, g_2}, …} setting work?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot some wavefronts in Mathematica, and I'm having some trouble reining in one of the options for my ContourPlot3D.

More specifically, the documentation for [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) says that the `Contours` option can be used in the form

```
ContourPlot3D[
  x^3 + y^2 - z^2
  , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}
  , Contours -> {{-2, Red}, {2, Blue}}
  , Mesh -> None
]
```

to produce contours at those levels and with those colours, but when I try to implement that I get some pretty wonky behaviour. As a minimal example, consider the following plane wave:

```
L = π + 0.001;
ContourPlot3D[
 Arg[Exp[I z]]
 , {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}
 , Contours -> Table[{ϕ, Hue[(ϕ + π)/(2 π)]}, {ϕ, -π, π, π/3}]
 , Mesh -> None
 ]
```

Unfortunately, it produces some pretty paltry output,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with a bunch of contours missing. Weirdly enough, these contours do appear if I give it numerical values for the contours:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Arg[Exp[I z]]
 , {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}
 , Contours -> Table[{N[ϕ], Hue[(ϕ + π)/(2 π)]}, {ϕ, -π, π, π/3}]
 , Mesh -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's going on here? Is this a bug?

Comment: Well, this doesn't work right, either (dropping `Hue`): `ContourPlot3D[Arg[Exp[I z]], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, Contours -> Table[\[Phi], {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/3}], Mesh -> None]`

Comment: @Michael Huh, I just skipped that step. Yeah, that's some buggy behaviour right there.

Comment: Part of the problem is that ` Arg[Exp[I z]]` is discontinuous over the interval `{z, -L ,L}` and jumps over several contours near `±L`.  That's probably confusing the mesher.

Comment: @JasonB That does seem like a bug, since `Contours -> {N@\[Pi]/3}` works fine.

Comment: I'm gonna report this internally, but it doesn't really seem to be related to the form `{val,_color}` or to the `Arg` function.  Compare the output of `ContourPlot3D[z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 5}, 
 Contours -> N /@ {\[Pi], E, EulerGamma}]` to `ContourPlot3D[z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 5}, 
 Contours -> {\[Pi], E, EulerGamma}]`

Comment: @JasonB Yeah, I reported it externally as well (case 3674416). That's a nice MWE, too.

Comment: @JasonB Just heard back, they sort of agree it's a bug. (They still blame it on the discontinuity, even after I gave them your example, though, so it might help to have some internal prodding.) If you answerify that comment I'm happy to accept this.